# why And-engine is completely blackout on onResume overrided function?

Tags: android, andengine

I am using AndEngine GLES 2.0. sometime when I resume my activity there is a complete blackout in the game. Although update and touch events of sprites are working but there is a complete blackout on screen. what is the problem?

Comment: You must give more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem is solved now. Blackout is due to the memory management. I was loading engine every time user plays the new Map. One should load engine for only one time and use Layers.

Answer (score 1):

AndEngine assumes the EGL context was invalidated, and thus must reload all your resources.  This typically takes a non-negligible amount of time, causing a black screen.

Efforts are underway to eliminate this problem on Android 3.0+ where possible, but it will likely always affect Android 2.x